# Top of Page Javascript Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Can anyone tell me how to turn

```
<a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)"> Top</a>
```

aka the Top of Page link into a Bookmarklet.

Not very knowledgeable with JavaScript and cannot get this into want I want it to be.

Or if I am using the wrong code, then can you fix it for me and turn it into the bookmarklet.

Answer (score 8):

Create a bookmark with location:

```
javascript:void(function(){window.scroll(0,0)}())
```

Works in Firefox 3 and IE 7.

Comment: @J-P Except that it doesn't work in IE without it. Give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

Another option ...

```
function scrollUp(){
  var offy;
  if(self.pageYOffset) {
        offy = self.pageYOffset;
  } else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop){
        offy = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  } else {
        offy = document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  if(offy <= 0) return;

  window.scrollBy(0, -50);
  setTimeout("scrollUp()", 10);
```

}

```
<a href="javascript: scrollUp();">Start Scroller!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an article from my bookmarks .. its a simple and easy solution that I have been using for a long time now.

http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/web_development/javascript/tips_and_tricks/javascript_go_to_top_of_page.php

hope this works